# Search bar not working just crash

Tags: sqlite, search

here is code for my database
SQLiteTutorialAppDelegate.m

`$`.-(void) readAnimalsFromDatabase {

```
sqlite3 *database;
animals = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

    const char *sqlStatement = "select * from animals";
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            // Read the data from the result row
            NSString *aName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
            NSString *aDescription = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];
            NSString *aImageUrl = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 3)];

            // Create a new animal object with the data from the database
            Animal *animal = [[Animal alloc] initWithName:aName description:aDescription url:aImageUrl];

            // Add the animal object to the animals Array
            [animals addObject:animal];

            [animal release];
        }
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

}
sqlite3_close(database);
```

}

and here RootViewController.m

`$`.- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)SearchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

```
[copyListOfItems removeAllObjects];
NSMutableArray *searchArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
SQLiteTutorialAppDelegate *appDelegate = (SQLiteTutorialAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

for (NSArray *rowArray in appDelegate.animals)
    {
        for ( NSString *aName in rowArray )

```
    {

        [searchArray addObject:rowArray]; // HERE CRASH 
    }
}


for (NSString *sTemp in searchArray)
{
    NSRange titleResultsRange = [sTemp rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

    if (titleResultsRange.length == 0)
        [copyListOfItems addObject:sTemp];
}

[self.tableView reloadData];
```

}

please help me how to make search bar search database in TableView

Answer (score 0):

http://www.appcoda.com/search-bar-tutorial-ios7/

This gives you an example of how the search bar uses things around it and how it works

I Recently worked on something similar and this website should tell you everything wrong as well as give you an example of how it works

Comment: Please summarize the content of your link. We want answers to be useful to future visitors if the link gets broken.